# Is it possible to predict rand(0,10) in PHP?

Tags: php, math

I have a script where I use the rand function in PHP. Now I read some ghost stories that its real easy to predict those outcomes. Is this possible from the client-side?

For example, let say we have a `rand(0,10)`. Is it possible to predict the next number?

Comment: They're not ghost stories, `rand()` is **NOT** a cryptographically secure random number generator.

Comment: By looking into source code of `rand()`?

Comment: If you have just the last result, no, you cannot predict the next one. If you have a sufficiently long string of results, then predicting the next becomes increasingly easy.

Comment: These are what is known as pseudo random variables.  This means that over a HUGE sample, you have a reasonable chance of predicting what will be the most common results.  But knowing the next result based on the existing result, if you don't set the seed would be almost impossible.

Comment: Random number generators on computers are generally, *pseudo* random number generators.  They take a seed, typically the current time, and perform a series of mathematical operations on the seed number to get a new "random" number.  If you know the operations, and know the seed, it is predictable.

Comment: Check out the answers over at Programmers':

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76229/predicting-the-output-of-phps-rand

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot that generator may give you periodic series of random numbers. If it's the case with PHP `rand`, once you have full period of values, predicting value in next cycle is trivial.

Comment: @VictorSorokin this is true only when calling `rand` multiple times in the same request. PHP is started (and rand seeded) with every request again.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`rand()` function returns a pseudorandom number .
This does NOT mean that the `next` number can be predicted.
However this image can explain the concept of word `pseudorandom`

[image: rand]

You can read this [article](http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html)

the image is generated from a simple loop with `rand` function on windows system.

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(512, 512) or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
for ($y = 0; $y < 512; $y++) {
    for ($x = 0; $x < 512; $x++) {
        if (rand(0, 1)) {
            imagesetpixel($im, $x, $y, $white); 
        } 
    } 
} 
imagepng($im); imagedestroy($im);
```

It's not so random, really? But now that you know it... you can predict the next number?

> The difference between true random number generators (TRNGs) and pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs) is that TRNGs use an unpredictable physical means to generate numbers (like atmospheric noise), and PRNGs use mathematical algorithms (completely computer-generated)
>
> [...]
>
> Not many PRNGs will produce an obvious visual pattern like this, it just so happens to be a really bad combination of language (PHP), operating system (Windows), and function (rand()).

Comment: Really loved the explanation in the post!

Comment: if it was really random, it would look like white noise :)

Comment: This is image from large for loop, or from many http requests? Hm?

Comment: This picture illustrates it very good. As you can see it builds a pattern and you can always make good predictions out of patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'm surprised that there are patterns in the php rand() function. But over a sample of 10 numbers I don't have to worry!

Comment: I executed that PHP code on PHP5.4 on Linux. [This is the result](http://imageshack.us/a/img254/8725/randomh.png).

Comment: @Francesco I've specified: on `windows` system. (I've tested it one year ago and is according with this image).

Comment: I've re-tested with php 5.3 on windows system and the result is "the same"

Comment: I have read the test was made on Windows. I just wanted to try it on Linux to see if differed.

Comment: I executed that code on PHP5.5.4 Ubuntu 32-bit. [This is the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/N7J81.png).

Answer (score 7):

You'd have to brute-force the state of the PRNG. http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf

PHP's rand() uses the underlying standard library implementation, this is different based on the operating system.

So first step, define the operating system.

Next step, get the source code for the Rand() function and the code that seeds it.

For simplicity lets assume the seed for the PRNG is something like the millisecond time of the server. So, the HTTP request comes in, PHP seeds the PRNG and executes rand(0,10). If you want to predict that you would...

- Sync your client's clock to the server's, statistically deriving the exact time from sending HTTP request to the server and reading the response HTTP header with the time stamp.
- Seed your client PRNG (that is the same implementation as the server's) with a predicted future time that you will request rand(0,10) from the server. Run rand(0,10) on the client, send the request at the exact future time to the server and the results would be the same.
- Ping times, processing times, etc make this a fairly brute-force approach.

Really, over the internet (not having direct access to the server), you aren't going to have much luck predicting the results of PHP's rand() function.

Answer (score 1):

From the [rand manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php):

> A pseudo random value between min (or 0) and max (or getrandmax(),
>   inclusive).

So, random is not random, but pseudo random. If you know how the caluclation is done, and know the initial value one can predict (calculate) the next value.

If you need a *true random value*, you need a other algorithm. Based on *white noise*, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned by `rand()` is only a *pseudo random* value.

This means, that it might be possible to calculate the number if you got access to the machine, but that's still really unlikely to happen. A end-user which just sees the output of PHP and has no access to machine has no possible option of calculation or predicting the next value. The output of multiple `rand()` calls within **ONE** execution of a php script might *technically *be predictable, but this cannot be used anway, because the user does only see the output of **ONE WHOLE** execution, having no chance to interact while the PHP script is executing.

This is the procedure used to generate the seed for PHP's `rand()`:

```
#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((long) (time(0) * GetCurrentProcessId())) ^ ((long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C))))
#else
#define GENERATE_SEED() (((long) (time(0) * getpid())) ^ ((long) (1000000.0 * php_combined_lcg(TSRMLS_C))))
#endif
```

As of PHP `4.2.0`,  [`The random number generator is seeded automatically.`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may want to differentiate between secure and secure enough.  The answer to your question about prediction is "yes," it is possible to predict numbers generated from a pseudo random number generator.  However, I think that the more important question is how likely this is to occur.  What are you trying to protect from prediction?  If you are running a massive online gaming website it is probably more important to have true randomness than if you are running a small MUD server.  It is more important because the consequences of a user breaking the pattern are more severe and there is a higher likelihood that a user will have the motivation to spend time attacking your algorithm.

You might also want to look at the services of Random.org.  They provide an API that allows you to pull true random numbers from their servers.  They get their entropy from atmospheric noise, which should be unpredictable at least as far as your users are concerned.

http://www.random.org/clients/http/

Answer (score -3):

Do not trust these ghost stories. For webapps, prediction is impossible and next number cannot be determined from the client side.

Why?

Because random number generator is seeded before every request and client cannot see the seed value! Prediction works only if all numbers were generated in the same request.

- row of many numbers will not be really random
- next number (in the following http request) cannot be determined from the client side

Comment: `Because random number generator is seeded before every request`: this is false.

Comment: You are wrong. http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php : "Note: As of PHP 4.2.0, there is no need to seed the random number generator with srand() or mt_srand() as this is now done automatically."

Comment: The random number generator is **only** seeded automatically **after** the request to the server has been made and **if and only if** `rand()` has been called within the script. (See [the source](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/rand.c)). Not only can the client not see the seed value, it's not exposed to any PHP script.

Comment: Seeding your random-number generator with a non-random value produces more pseudo-random values.

Comment: @Petr: It is done automatically every time you load the page. If you call random multiple time in the same page it won't be reseeded.