# is truncated mt_rand() safer?

Tags: php, c, security, random

I came across those articles:

- http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html
- http://crypto.di.uoa.gr/CRYPTO.SEC/Randomness_Attacks_files/paper.pdf

which show how to recover a seed of the `mt_rand()` function. Attached code can brute force seed from the first mt_rand() in a one minute (or faster). The truth is that most of the PHP applications use mt_rand with range arguments. This truncates the result. My question is does it make it more difficult to crack? For a start I can imagine that one can't brute force it with just a one number. He need to have a whole sequence. Does it make the cracking process significantly longer or it doesn't really matter? Is `mt_rand(from, to)` much more secure than `mt_rand()`?

Comment: great explaination about the rand functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729459/is-it-possible-to-predict-rand0-10-in-php

Comment: Just an aside, but if you need to be safe from this sort of thing because something important depends on it, you want to use a cryptographically secure RNG rather than trying to hack up your own.

Comment: If it's for security, use a cryptographic PRNG. Such as `mcrypt_create_iv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calling `mt_rand($min, $max)` is basically equivalent to the following](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L311):

```
$rand_in_range_min_to_max = (int)($min + ($max - $min) * ($rand/mt_getrandmax()));
```

So instead of having the random number picked from the theoretical range from 0 to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, you have the number picked from `$min` to `$max` instead. And if `$min` is larger than `0` or `$max` less than `1<<31-1`, this alone does already reduce the amount of possible seed values.

Now since [the presented attack](http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Insufficient-Entropy-For-Random-Values.html) is a brute-force attack, reducing the number of guesses does also reduce the time to complete the brute-force process.

However, since the resulting value from the brute-force process is no the actual random value but only the value that the random value was mapped onto, an attacker would need to check each possible input value that is mapped onto that brute-forced value. That range can be calculated as follows:

```
$rand_min = (int)(($rand_in_range_min_to_max - $min) / ($max - $min) * mt_getrandmax());
$rand_max = (int)($rand_min + mt_getrandmax() / ($max - $min + 1));

// range whose values are mapped onto $rand_in_range_min_to_max
$range = range($rand_min, $rand_max);
foreach ($range as $rand) {
    assert($rand_in_range_min_to_max === (int)($min + ($max - $min) * ($rand/mt_getrandmax())));
}
```

As each of the numbers in the range are getting mapped identically, they all are only potential numbers for generating the next random number in sequence. To unmistakably identify the actual number, an attacker would need at most `mt_getrandmax() / ($max - $min)` subsequently generated random numbers.

So, actually, using `mt_rand($min, $max)` *does* increase the effort for an attacker to find the actual seed as he has to brute-force seeds for multiple random values and he would need `mt_getrandmax() / ($max - $min)` subsequently generated random numbers to uniquely identify the right seed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it's very helpful. Just to help me understand better is that not going to return many potential seeds? For example is the range is 0,1 than 50% of assertion will be TRUE. That's going to be lots of results where only one is the correct one?

Comment: @LukaszKujawa There is a difference whether you want to identify the seed to be able to predict the next random number or whether you just want to be able to predict the next hash value. In case of the latter, when `mt_rand(0, 1)` is chosen, you already have a 50-50 chance to guess the next number correctly. However, if the random number is mapped onto a smaller range like `mt_rand` with *min* and *max* does, you’ll get multiple probable seeds which all are mapped identically. In that case you would need more numbers in sequence to correctly identify the initially used seed.