# PHP SourceCode Random

Tags: php, random

The function for `rand()` should be something like `(SEED * A + C) mod M`.

How can I find the values of `A`, `C`, and `M`? And if I find those values, can I predict the next number in the sequence?

I know that I can find the values of these variables in the PHP source code. But after looking around I really cannot find them...

Does anybody know what file it would be in? Or who else I could contact (I've tried email *internals@lists.php.net* but haven't got a response)

Also I'm doing all this in PHP versions prior to 7, where `rand()` and `mt_rand()` became synonymous.

EDIT: I have seen Is it possible to predict rand(0,10) in PHP? but those answers aren't about the constant values in PHP's rand() value by themselves.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think these values are accessible from within an executing PHP script. Why should they be? Anyway, the random function in PHP should be seen as a black box, and what on earth can be the point of predicting the next number? I really cannot think of one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to predict rand(0,10) in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729459/is-it-possible-to-predict-rand0-10-in-php)

Comment: Also cf this question on softwareengineering@stackexchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76229/predicting-the-output-of-phps-rand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the old school `rand()` function used a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator).

This [generator is system dependent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634079/glibc-rand-function-implementation). One algorithm employed by glibc was:

```
next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
return next & 0x7fffffff;
```

so there you have your constants. The state, of course, is the initial value of 'next', which is zero unless set differently by `srand()`.

There are ways of attacking a linear congruence; one possibility - the slowest, but the easiest to explain - is to *brute force* it. Say that you four consecutive values: a0, a1, a2, a3 from your rand() implementation. You can check all values of seed that would yield that same sequence.

Note that if your a0 value is produced by, say, rand() % 7172, then your initial seed must obey the rule that "seed % 7172 === a0". This immediately reduces the space you need to brute force, speeding up operations proportionately. Also, you don't need to check all four numbers.

This would be the efficient equivalent of running (in PHP)

```
for ($seed = 0; $seed < MAX_SEED; $seed++) {
    srand($seed);
    if ($a0 !== [RAND() FORMULA]) return false;
    if ($a1 !== [RAND() FORMULA]) return false;
    if ($a2 !== [RAND() FORMULA]) return false;
    if ($a3 !== [RAND() FORMULA]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

## Experiments

By checking with a reference trivial C source code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        srand(1);
        printf("%ld\n", rand());
}
```

I determined that PHP and C do indeed share the same underlying function (I tabulated different values for srand()).

I also found out that srand(0) and srand(1) yield the same result, which isn't consistent with my linear model.

And that's because [glibc rand()](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=stdlib/random.c;h=43bdb1232eea5326a42e3637c57aa8cbe0b93dfd;hb=refs/heads/master) is not *so* trivial a linear congruential generator. More info [here](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/). Actually it is quoted in a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634079/glibc-rand-function-implementation) and the code I had was for the old, TYPE_0 generator.

Comment: Lets say that I can seed the function before. So I seed it with srand(0), does that mean that I just stick that in place of `next` and it should work? What about he Modulo part of the LCG? Also sorry, what does the `... & 0x7fffffff;` part of your code mean? Kind of a noob here :p

Comment: `<?php
$next = 1;
srand(1);



$next = $next * 1103515245 + 12345;
print "Predicted: ";
print $next % 0x7fffffff;

print " Actual:";
print rand();
?>` So i've tried this code, and I'm getting different answers for my predicted values and actual values... Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Are you running with the Suhosin patch? That would disable srand().

Comment: Hi, I just checked and I'm not running with the Suhosin patch, know anything that could help me out? Thanks so much

Comment: I found out why. See updated answer. It turns out that you *can* predict the output of PHP rand(), but not so easily. The approach is the same, the implementation is much more complex.

Comment: Thank you so much, this completely solved my problem. You're a lifesaver :)